# Grid component performance

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Just thinking and a question round my mind. I use to code xaml using grid, easier for me, at least. Just define the grid and using its cells (span row and column and so on...).

Doing a web´s demo today I remember table´s tag is being obsolote and I am wondering, the same idea could be applied to grid in mobile´s app.

Thinking about it, absolute and relative layout are similar to div (web speaking) so we could deduce the right way to render the xaml should be using those kind of layouts...

What do you think guys? What advantages and deficiencies are coming on using those approaches? I want to get use to code thinking in the best way, not thinking about easyness of that (supposing, that benefit me in long terms. Maintainability, flexibility,...).

As usual, thanks for your help mates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the point is the next one. As web design do, using layout (relative and absolute) like div could be more complex at the beggining, but after the project is growing up, the benefits of using these approaches take relevance with the time.

If you need to change the style of the view, these layout are more flexible for doing it, just set the limits of the each element and you can add another element as well in a easy way.

But if you decided to use grid layout approach, and after, you need to change the style, the operation will be more complicated because you probably need to reset the definition of column and row for adding new elements and this implicate to recode every row and column for the other rows as well.

Hoping it helps when you are in design phase and you need to calculate risk and maintainability of your app.

Cheers mates...